# How to add a constraing to the splitting based on multiple delimiters?

Tags: python

I want to split the following values using multiple delimiters `+/,.;`. All the other signs should not be used as delimiters.

For example,

```
CAP.44,45+62(400)
e.morgan,44+32/78
```

I wrote the following code:

```
import re
data['COUNT'] = data['STRING_VALS'].apply(lambda x: len(re.findall(r'[+/,.; ]+', x)))
```

The problem is that `.` might have an exception. It should not be used as a delimiter in case of the following mask `_.___`. So, if there is one character before `.` and any number of characters after `.`, then `_.___` should not be splitted.

How to add such mask-based constraint to the the above-given code?

Comment: What about `a.b.c`? How many parts should it be split into?

Comment: @AlexHall:Then it should be split into 3 parts.

Comment: That's not what I expected. So you want to avoid splitting on dot only if there's one non-dot character before and more than one after? Should `a.bb.c.dd` be split into `a.bb` and `c.dd`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead.
Something like :

`r'[\s+/,;]|(?<!_)[.](?!___)'`

Such that:

`p = re.compile(r'[\s+/,;]|(?<!_)[.](?!___)')
re.split(p, 'CAP.44,45+62(400)')`

returns: `['CAP', '44', '45', '62(400)']`

But

`re.split(p, '_.___')`

returns: `['_.___']`

Comment: Thanks. I tested it. A little problem is that strings like `tyt-21-47-rut` have a length 3 instead of 4.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get what you mean.